# Show time since last ajax call

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a table with data from ajax call and I was request to show date after each refresh.

I thought of making a counter that shows how many seconds or minutes have passed after last refresh but i cannot seem to do this. So far what i have is this, but this only counts seconds and i have to do more checking if i want to show in minutes

```
    var timestamp = 0;
        function updateTime() {
            $('#refreshDate').html(timestamp + "seconds ago");
            timestamp++;
        }
        $(function () {
            setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
        });
```

Well the outcome should be something similar to stackoverflow on posts, like it shows when posts were created x seconds ago or minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p id="lastRefresh">Wait.....</p>

<script>
    function setTime(){
       var date = new Date();
       timestamp = date.getTime();
    }

    //Call setTime when you make initial call
    setTime();

    //Set the delay here in ms 
    var updateDelay = 15000;

    var lastRefresh = document.getElementById("lastRefresh");      

    function updateLastRefreshTime() {        
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var currentTime = currentDate.getTime();
      var timeSince = Math.floor((currentTime - timestamp)/1000);
      let timeStampDescription = "";        

      // year
      if(timeSince > 31536000){;
        timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timeSince/31536000) + " years ago"
      // Days
      } else if(timeSince > 86400){
        timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timeSince/86400) + " days ago"
      // Hours
      } else if(timeSince > 3600){
        timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timeSince/3600) + " hours ago"
      // Minutes
      } else if(timeSince > 60) {
        timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timeSince/60) + " minutes ago"
      // Seconds
      } else{ 
        timeStampDescription = timeSince + " seconds ago"
      }
      lastRefresh.innerText = timeStampDescription;          
     }        
     setInterval(updateLastRefreshTime, updateDelay);        

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: this only counts seconds, does not format time like stackoverflow tho

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much does meet all the requirements, if you can update your question code i will mark it as right answer

Comment: I have updated the code, It contains  Chizzele's update method slightly improvised. If you are fine with this you can mark this as a right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it up to years

```
var timestamp = 0;
function updateTime() {
  let timeStampDescription = "";
  // year
  if(timestamp > 31536000){
    timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timestamp/31536000) + " years ago"
  // Days
  } else if(timestamp > 86400){
    timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timestamp/86400) + " days ago"
  // Hours
  } else if(timestamp > 3600){
    timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timestamp/3600) + " hours ago"
  // Minutes
  } else if(timestamp > 60) {
    timeStampDescription = Math.floor(timestamp/60) + " minutes ago"
  // Seconds
  } else{ 
    timeStampDescription = timestamp + " seconds ago"
  }
    $('#refreshDate').html(timeStampDescription);
    timestamp++;
}
$(function () {
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
});
```

Comment: thanks, this works pretty nice but there is a problem, if i want to refresh this every 15 seconds instead of 1, it won't track the time

Comment: You really should be tracking the refresh time on the server side, and at the very least if you are going to do it on the client side, use localStorage or sessionStorage so that the time persists, I could update my code to show this?

Comment: sure that would be nice

Comment: I will treat time refreshed as the time you load the page, which will save that into a variable in sessionStorage, that will then be updated when the page refreshes again, I wont have time to do this for a while however, so maybe try and implement that in the time being

Comment: Nice reading back on the question this is probably a good way to go about it, I interpreted the question as him wanting to have the time since last refresh remain, so by keeping it in storage we could store a timestamp and then do a calculation to get how long ago that was, but this solution works if he simply wants to know how long he has been on the page for

Comment: If he gives confirmation on which he wants, I will update my code to include the edit :)

Comment: Murali Nepalli pretty much got what i was looking for! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also just to clarilfy, the intended was when page loaded, table loads data using ajax, and evey x seconds shows how much time has passed since table was refreshed. So whenever i call the ajax function manually the time function can also be called besides on page load

Answer (score 1):

You can even calculate the time from now using [moment](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/02-fromnow)

```
      var myDate = new Date();
      var lastRefresh = document.getElementById("lastRefresh");
      function updateTime() {                              
          lastRefresh.innerText = moment(myDate).fromNow(); // which returns something like: "2 seconds ago"
      }

      setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: Updated the answer in your context